# Overwrite sum behavior on a custom class inhering from an iterable (list)

Tags: python

Is there any way I can over write the `sum()` method to act differently on a list?

I expected I would be able to find a dunder method that would allow me to define my own implementation, but I couldn't.

That's how I'd imagine the implementation

```
class MyDummyList(list):
    def __sum__(self): -> str:
        return 'a'

x = MyDummyList()
print(sum(x)) -> # prints 'a'
```

Obviously this breaks as there is no dunder method `__sum__` but I am somewhat surprised that there is no such a way to do that using dunder methods as sum is a quite common operation on iterables.

Comment: Is there a reason you want it to be a dunder method?

Comment: Not really, just expected to see it implemented as it seems a very common custom behavior on iterables, but if there is none then ok, I expected to have seen one.\

Comment: Obviously, you can implement x.sum() with `sum` being an (inefficient) iterator over a class list.

Comment: still I want to use the wrapper around the object sum(iterbale) not iterable.sum()

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136507/how-to-implement-built-in-sum-of-the-class (correcting my earlier close vote)